# How install R and shiny package on ubuntu server and publish it on shiny-server without launching browser

Tags: r, ubuntu, airflow, shiny-server

I am pretty new to R and Shiny apps, so please accept my apology if it seems a bit stupid question.
So, basically what I want is to automate a shiny app dashboard which currently I am running from my windows machine.
I fetch hourly data from my database and save a file in the working directory of R.

Steps I follow:

1. Open R studio
2. Run my Shiny App and it generates a dashboard on my localhost 'http://127.0.0.1:7790/'
3. I click the button on the top right side of it to called "Publish" to publish my dashboard on shiny server "https://www.shinyapps.io"

Now I run this process almost every hour manually. I have my **Apache Airflow** running on one of my ubuntu server.

So, I am willing to install **R, Shiny** package on my **ubuntu** server and from there would like call the shiny app and publish my dashboard on shiny server.
Once I am able to call it from the command line then I think the rest will be easy to schedule it on my **Airflow** tool to run on hourly basis.

Obviusly, I don't want to launch the browser while publishing my shinyApp on shiny server.

Any help on this will be a great help to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to publish your shiny dashboard? Have you tried shiny server? It's open source and you can set it up in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to automate my shiny app from my ubuntu server.
I have my Apache Airflow tool already up and running on the Ubuntu server on AWS.
Assuming that you want to deploy it from the server, please run the below commands to install R-base and dependencies:

`sudo su -c "echo 'deb http://archive.linux.duke.edu/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"`

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y`

`sudo apt-get install r-base -y`

`sudo su --c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""`

`sudo su --c "R -e \"install.packages('fpp', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""`

`sudo su --c "R -e \"install.packages('rmarkdown', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""`

`sudo su --c "R -e \"install.packages('ggplot2', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""`

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev`

Post successful installation of R, Shiny and required packages, we will check if the R is installed successfully (You will see the interactive R terminal as below):

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

>
```

Run below command from R terminal to install dependencies and rsconnect package:
`install.packages('devtools')`

`install.packages('rsconnect')`

Type 'q()' to exit the R terminal.
Now we need to set the working directory in R in our sudo command to deploy the dashboard on shinyapps.io webserver server. Before running the command make sure you already added token in the R. You can goggle it or may refer to the below link:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html

Now run the below command to deploy the app on shinyapps.io:

```
sudo -i R -e "rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = '/your/ubuntu/Directory_Path', launch.browser = FALSE, forceUpdate = TRUE)"
```